# Assigning Tasks to a Queue with DataLoader

Tags: data-loader, tasks, queue

I am looking to upload several thousand tasks to my org with DataLoader assigned to a shared Queue.

I am assigning the OwnerID as the 18 digit Queue ID in my csv file.

However, upon attempting to upload the error reads:

`SOURCE: 'OwnerId' DESTINATION: 'OwnerId' ERROR:Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: 00G5g000000Oy72EAC`

I have exported the existing tasks in the org that are in the queue, and they show the same id.

Comment: give this a try https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353572&type=1

Answer (score 0):

This may be because your **queue** is not configured to be used on Tasks. If this is the case, you need to edit the queue and add "**Task**" to the supported objects.

[image: Look here for a visual reference]